# $facebook.getUser(); returning all the time 0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting here due to a problem with php and the sdk of facebook.

For a reason I don't really know, when I try to get the userID of the logged account, continuously I received the same value, 0, even if i'm logged.

I've been trying to debug some variables, $facebook, checking sessions, etc. but with unsuccessfully results, then i'm gonna step by detailing all what i'm doing and the debug log i'm doing:

I'm using hostinger servers, that hosts my website. Due to i've found many problems, i've created a test webpage in which i have 5 files: 
index.php

```
callback.php
facebook.php (comes from facebook)
base_facebook.php
certificate
```

The code i have on index.php is what i've pasted here: [index.php]: http://pastebin.com/Mfdkxz8H This is only the first part of the code which tries to get the autentification.

The code i have on callback.php is what i've pasted here: [callback.php]: http://pastebin.com/Uw0A3NM8. There i try to get the userID.

I've read some post and for some reasons there were so many cases in which the token 
wasn't received in the second file/call.

I don't really know what the problem is and would be happy to find a solution.

P.D It doesn't matter the appId and secret because facebook and webpage were created for a test.

Comment: One hundred answered questions on this already. Have you checked them all?

Comment: i've taken like 3-4 days trying to find a solution via help, other similar topics related to my problem and even conctacting facebook but I still have the same problem. Since some days I start thinking the problem is my server that doesn't allow me to conect facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what is going up from your code example (**By the way, you should NEVER post your appId and secret in public like that otherwise someone will be able to compromise your application**). A gave your code a quick glance and it "looks" fine but here are a couple of pointers:

But here are a couple of pointers.
1) Make sure you have the latest version of the Facebook SDK (assuming you do)
2) For SANITY sake, i would keep your Facebook API files in its their folder ('sdk')
3) DOUBLE CHECK your app settings to make sure the appID and secret are correct (I have made this mistake many times), also make sure that your at is NOT in sandbox mode 
4) Then try something like this

```
include_once("sdk/facebook.php");

//Call Facebook API
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
  'secret' => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://devstarlight.esy.es/facebook/callback.php'
);

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: After investigating about the issue, in my old code i discovered that i wasn't getting any result from facebook in the callback.php when i was even calling $facebook->getUser() but now, i request first the code, and after the token without trying to get any information about the user and i can see the user in my SESSIONS/COOKIES. Here's the new code

http://pastebin.com/yG1Nj2Eq

May I just try to get the User from the cookie and that's all?

Comment: I would suggest you use the latest version of the facebook php-sdk and combine it with the js-sdk .The github src for the php sdk includes an example of combing it with th js-sdk. This handles a reload of the page once a user authenticates and creates the cookie